# Best leaderboard service which supports both android and iOS

Tags: android

I am developing a android-ios game. There are a no of 3rd party services for implementing leaderboards in smartphone games like , `Google Play Game Services` , `www.scoreloop.com`, [swarm](http://swarmconnect.com/) etc. Which one is best in your experience/opinion ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way is to implement leaderboards for android with Google Play Games Services (https://developers.google.com/games/services/) and for ios – with their own Game Center (https://developer.apple.com/game-center/).
I think this is most comfortable for users to have platform-specific game service. As they can feel comfortable with this.

But if you want one leaderboard both for android and ios I would rather prefer Google Play Games Services.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why ?

Comment: In fact, I don't know why exactly. I think this is because I like android/google much more than ios/apple, and also if I can use some "official" stuff from google, I'd prefer to use it.
There are no problems with scoreloop, for example. Scoreloop is pretty well